# How is ArrayListMultimap different from LinkedListMultimap?

Tags: java, guava

So, I was just reading the javadoc for `ArrayListMultimap` and `LinkedListMultimap` so as to understand how to use them and I came to know that both support duplicate key-value pair (and by that I mean same keys, different values - if I understand correctly. Please correct me if I am wrong). However, I don't understand the difference between them. Both are used to store duplicate key value pairs. Is the only part they differ is in their implementation i.e `ArrayListMultimap` is implemented as an Array and `LinkedListMultimap` is implemented as a LinkedList? Also, how do they differ in performance? I know I am asking a lot but I don't really know where else to find answers for this.

Comment: anyone have a good example of when a `LinkedListMultimap` is useful (compared to just an `ArrayListMultimap`)? _by example I don't mean code - just a situation_

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's in the docs... and in the code. Basically besides one difference you've already seen (`List` implementation choice), they also use a different `Map` implementation. So:

- `ArrayListMultimap` uses `HashMap` for map and `ArrayList` cor collection, which means that iteration order of such methods as `entries()`, `asMap().keySet()` or `asMap.entrySet()` is undefined. It's plain and simple implementation of `ListMultimap` and you should start with this one.
- `LinkedListMultimap` uses `LinkedList` for collection and specialized data structure (custom linked list) to maintain iteration order of methods mentioned above:

  > Order is maintained using a linked list containing all key-value
  >   pairs. In    addition, a series of disjoint linked lists of
  >   "siblings", each containing    the values for a specific key, is used
  >   to implement *ValueForKeyIterator* in constant time.

  Additionally it uses few other structures to maintain "linked list"-like behavior:

  ```
  private transient Node<K, V> head; // the head for all keys
  private transient Node<K, V> tail; // the tail for all keys
  private transient Multiset<K> keyCount; // the number of values for each key
  private transient Map<K, Node<K, V>> keyToKeyHead; // the head for a given key
  private transient Map<K, Node<K, V>> keyToKeyTail; // the tail for a given key
  ```

Also, memory footprint is a implication of backing collections used in these `Multimap` implementations - [see this comparision](https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer/blob/master/ElementCostInDataStructures.txt) (may not be 100% up to date).

---

Personally, when I need efficient, mutable `ListMultimap` with defined iteration order of keys, I use "custom" `ListMultimap` (created with [`MultimapBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html), which is in Guava since v16.0):

```
ListMultimap<String, Integer> treeListMultimap = 
    MultimapBuilder.linkedHashKeys().arrayListValues().build();
```

---

Before v16.0 creating custom `Multimap`s was more verbose (using [`Multimaps.newListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newListMultimap%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier%29)):

```
/**
 * Creates {@link ListMultimap} preserving insertion order of keys and values 
 * (it's backed by {@link LinkedHashMap} and {@link ArrayList}).
 */
public static <K, V> ListMultimap<K, V> newLinkedArrayListMultimap() {
  return Multimaps.newListMultimap(
      Maps.<K, Collection<V>>newLinkedHashMap(),
      new Supplier<List<V>>() {
          @Override
          public List<V> get() {
            return Lists.newArrayList();
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: amazing answer!