# Implementing multi key-value map

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a situation where I need to have a key-value pair data structure. But it should allow multiple keys and values corresponding to that.

It would be like :

> a - 1
>
> b - 2
>
> a - 3

So, when retrieving, I can have `getFirstValueOfKey(key)` and get 1...something like that.

Is there something existing or I need to implement this?

If I need to implement this, I am thinking to proceed as :

Create a class, which a=can hold K-V pairs, and add them to a list. And write corresponding API's required. Is this right approach? Shall I continue like this?

**EDIT :** I actually want multiple entries of keys in the data structure.

**EDIT :** The thing is, I want to maintain order in which new entries(keys) were made, i.e. I want to have sequence of keys how they are put, (a and then b and then a). If array of values is used, this sequence is lost.

Example :

a -> 1 (Time 0)
b -> 2 (Time 1)
a -> 3 (Time 2)

*These time stamps are also required.*

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html should do the trick

Comment: Could you also explain why do you need multiple keys? Do you want to rely on order of keys?

Comment: @ProblemFactory - yes, I want to rely on order of keys. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can have a look at `MultiMap` by [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) library from Google

> There are two ways to think of a Multimap conceptually: as a
>   collection of mappings from single keys to single values:
>
> a -> 1 a -> 2 a -> 4 b -> 3 c -> 5 or as a mapping from unique keys to
>   collections of values:
>
> a -> [1, 2, 4] b -> 3 c -> 5

Though you have a jar dependency, Guava collections are normally more concise and efficient

Comment: I want to rely on order of keys. Edited question.

Comment: then probably you need to use [LinkedListMultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap.html). Also see [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975681/how-is-arraylistmultimap-different-from-linkedlistmultimap). Though I haven't tested these myself.

Comment: This is what was required. :)

Comment: glad that it helped :-) would you then consider choosing it as the correct answer? cheers!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It looks like you are looking for `Map<Character, List<Integer>>`.</strike>

Since you edited question: 
to rely both on keys order and values per each key,

- you should use list of `Map.Entry` implementation, (for example `Pair` from Apache Commons), where: `List<Map.Entry<Character, List>> struct = new ArrayList<Pair<Character, ArrayList>>()`;
- or if you don't want to add additional libraries, instead of `Pair` you could use just `Map` (witch will always contains 1 key - your letter): `List<Map<Character, List>>`.

Comment: It's like, 1 key having multiple values, this is not required. I actually want multiple entries of keys.

Comment: @Batty I don't see the difference.  It all depends on how you access it.  If you want a `getFirstValueOfKey` operation, use the map `get` to get the list and then get the first element of the list.  It is not hard to get the program to see (key, [val1, val1, val3...]) as (key, val1), (key, val2), (key, val3) ...

Comment: @Batty, I don't understand your problem, you want have multiple keys and also keep order of values, my solution solve that problem. You can't rely on keys order in `Map`.

Comment: I want to rely on order of keys. Edited question.